# vsftpd - can't upload via upload tool but can with ftp client

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, nginx, vsftpd

I am using nginx as my web server and vsftpd for FTP access. I have all set up and a test site running which is accessible from the outside world. Also have an API backend that is also serving fine.

> Note: I have removed some sensitive info like domains and IPs where
>   applicable.

I can connect to the FTP server via FTP/FileZilla, browse, create folders and also files via FTP. I however am getting an error in the vsftpd log which is below. This happens when a tool on another machine auto uploads to the folder via FTP connection which I dont have much control over.

```
Tue Feb 18 10:20:09 2020 [pid 2536] [FTP_USER_ID] FAIL MKDIR: Client "::ffff:88.215.0.185", "/dev.test.com/folder1/folder2/folder3"
```

I de believe my permissions to be correct but Ill list them out here and hopefully someone can spot my mistake.

**Setting the Users $HOME to /var/www**

```
Command: getent passwd FTP_USER_ID
Result FTP_USER_ID :x:1001:1001:,,,:/var/www:/bin/bash
```

**Read set permissions for FTP user**
Command: ls -l /var/www

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 15 FTP_USER_ID FTP_USER_ID 4096 Feb 17 22:48 dev.example.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 FTP_USER_ID FTP_USER_ID 4096 Feb 17 01:51 html
```

**vsftpd.conf**

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022      
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES                                       
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
force_dot_files=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/dev.example.com;

        server_name dev. example.com;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        }

        location /api/ {

        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;

        }
}
```

> P.S: there's a beer in it for whoever works it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adjusting:
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO